# Add insert/update/delete triggers in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

Is there a way to add insert/update/delete triggers in Clickhouse to keep track of changes in a specific table to write data that has been changed to another table.

Here is a similar script for Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER
    INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON table_name
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   action_type VARCHAR2(6);
BEGIN
   action_type := CASE
         WHEN INSERTING THEN 'insert'
         WHEN UPDATING THEN 'update'
         WHEN DELETING THEN 'delete'
   END;

   INSERT INTO ...
END;
```

Comment: clickhouse doesn's support triggers
but support  MATERIALIZED VIEW which works as "after insert tirgger" on block level
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/view#materialized-view

Comment: @Slach got it, thanks.
So it's not possible to track "after update or delete" actions, right?

Comment: yes, right, as i said before, clickhouse doesn't support triggers

Comment: Actually ClickHouse is not really the right choice if you want to do frequent updates/deletions.